# WebRequest fails to get all source data from webpage

Tags: vb.net, webrequest

Hi I am using the below code to read  webpage in html :

```
Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://google.com")
Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse
Str = resp.GetResponseStream
srRead = New System.IO.StreamReader(Str)
TextBox1.Text = srRead.ReadToEnd
```

Here I replaced my original URL with google.com

When I right click on webpage and view the source I found the gridview in thet but when i read it through code then the code for that grid is invisible.

Why this happen...

Comment: This seems `vb.net` instead of `c#`.

Comment: Is is possible that this gridview are rendered on client side by JavaScript (maybe in response to AJAX calls)?